# Buttons not visible on MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, email, button, send, invisible

I have a project working with custom navigationBar. I have added the following code before the initialising `MFMailComposeViewController`

```
// Create image for navigation background - portrait
UIImage *navBar = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"HeaderStrip.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBar forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Create image for navigation background - landscape
UIImage *navBarL = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"HeaderStrip.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 100)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarL forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Here `HeaderStrip.png` is a simple red-colored image. Then in the following method, I've set the navigationBar back to original background image

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
```

Everything works as expected except the "Send" & "Cancel" buttons' visibility on the navigationBar of the mail composer. I've tried using tintColor before initialising `MFMailComposeViewController`:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Got no difference.

I've also tried seting `tintColor` of the `navigationBar` of the composer after allocating, result same:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer= [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailer.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Anyone got the solution of the issue? How to make the buttons visible?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: did you find the solution ?